# Periodic Timeout exception when I cancel OneDrive task that reads file information

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I use Microsoft Graph C# SDK for managing OneDrive files. My code works with storage in parallel way (max thread count < 6). For canceling an operation that is not valid anymore (user closes window or browses to another folder), I use a `CancellationToken`.

From time to time I receive a `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException` with the the code `Error.Code = GraphErrorCode.Timeout` when canceled tasks. This should be `OperationCanceledException`.

How to fix it?

Code is trivial, so I think these is a bug in Microsoft Graph. [There are a lot of similar questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmicrosoft-graph%5D+timeout).

SDK version is `1.7.0` (the same bug exists in `1.5.0` as well).

**Update:**

- It was invalid assumption that this bug is tied with others similar questions in StackOverflow.
- I've create bug on [MSGraph github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/223).

Comment: Update: We will be fixing this issue in the 2.0 release of the core Microsoft Library. See here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/pull/109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found this bug in [Microsoft Graph C# SDK](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet).

Please look at in [implementation of `HttpProvider.SendRequestAsync` method](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Core/Requests/HttpProvider.cs).
It contains following code:

```
    internal async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return await this.httpClient.SendAsync(request, completionOption, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException exception)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(
                    new Error
                    {
                        Code = ErrorConstants.Codes.Timeout,
                        Message = ErrorConstants.Messages.RequestTimedOut,
                    },
                    exception);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw new ServiceException(
                    new Error
                    {
                        Code = ErrorConstants.Codes.GeneralException,
                        Message = ErrorConstants.Messages.UnexpectedExceptionOnSend,
                    },
                    exception);
        }
    }
```

So as you see it transoms `TaskCanceledException` to `ServiceException` with  `Code = ErrorConstants.Codes.Timeout`. `TaskCanceledException` is exception that is threw by .NET 4.5 when task is canceled (`CancellationToken` is marked for cancel task). This exception class is inherited from `OperationCanceledException`.

I have only one question to MS - WHY!???
In many places of MSDN there are phrases about `OperationCanceledException` is important exception, it's used by .NET task managing code to verify cancellation reason and switch task to canceled state. Working method of task must not block this exception! If you analyze this exception in your task code you have to re-throw it for propagate out. In other way task will finished in failed state. Only code that run task and wait its finalization is able to catch this exception and analyze it. Please read - ["Parallel Tasks", section "Canceling a Task"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx)

> If the cancellation token indicates that a cancellation has been requested, the ThrowIfCancellationRequested method creates an OperationCanceledException instance and passes in the cancellation token. It then throws the exception. This exception is the signal that notifies the .NET Framework that the task has been canceled; therefore, ***the OperationCanceledException should not be handled by user code within the task*** (it is often handled, however, outside of the task that was canceled). If you follow the steps that have been described in this section, the task will be stopped and its Status property will be set to the enumerated value TaskStatus.Canceled.

Please remove `catch (TaskCanceledException exception)`.

**Update:**
Workaround in my code for fix this bug:

```
    // This method creates Task (because it's asynchronous) that can be canceled by token
    public async Task<DriveItem> MyUsefulMethodAsync(string driveId, string itemId, string selectItemParameter,  CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
    {
        DriveItem res = default(DriveItem);

        try
        {
            // My useful code, for example:
            res = await Client.Drives[driveId].Items[itemId].Request()
                    .Select(selectItemParameter)
                    .GetAsync(cancellationToken ?? CancellationToken.None);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // We have to propagate out this exception for fine Task state managing.
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // This is workaround for MSGraph bug (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47900445/987850)
            var se = e as ServiceException;
            if (se?.InnerException is OperationCanceledException)
            {
                throw se.InnerException;
            }

            // My error processing ...
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Example of usage:

```
    try
    {
        // cancellation token from token source (can be invoked to cancel state by UI handlers)
        var cancellationToken = m_bkCancelTokenSource.Token;

        var driveItem = await MyUsefulMethodAsync(driveId, itemId, "id, name, parentReference, file, remoteItem, size", cancellationToken);
        if (driveItem!=null)
        {
            // some code ...
        }
    }
    catch(OperationCanceledException)
    {
        // task was canceled by user
    }
```

Comment: Update: We will be fixing this issue in the 2.0 release of the core Microsoft Library. See here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/pull/109

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you're seeing it documented that you should be getting an `OperationCanceledException`. There isn't any methods in the SDK that generate this type of exception.

As for the `GraphErrorCode.Timeout`, this most likely means the request returned a `HTTP 504 Gateway Timeout`. This is a pretty generic error that simply means something in the call chain failed to return a result in time. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession#best-practices):

> Resume or retry uploads that fail due to connection interruptions or any `5xx` errors, including:
>
> - `500 Internal Server Error`
> - `502 Bad Gateway`
> - `503 Service Unavailable`
> - `504 Gateway Timeout`

Comment: C# task factory or task work method that can canceled by `CancellationToken` should periodically check this token and cancel its work if it's required. Usually it's done by [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_CancellationToken_ThrowIfCancellationRequested). This method throws [OperationCanceledException](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.operationcanceledexception?view=netframework-4.7.1).
It's common approach.

Comment: It may be a common approach but this is not one taken by the SDK

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be fixed in the upcoming 2.0 release of the core Microsoft Library. See here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/pull/109